# Read excel sheets from gcp bucket

Tags: gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am currently trying to read in data to my gcp notebook from a shared gcp storage bucket. I am an admin and so restrictions shouldn't apply as far as I know, but I am getting an error before I can even read in with pandas. Is this possible? Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

This is the code I have tried:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

client = storage.Client()
bucket = "our_data/deid"
blob = storage.blob.Blob("B_ACTIVITY.xlsx",bucket)

content = blob.download_as_string()

df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(content))
```

I was hoping for the data to simply be brought in once the bucket was specified, but I get an error "'str' object has no attribute 'path'".

Answer (score 1):

`bucket` needs to be a bucket object not just a string.

Try changing that line to

```
bucket = client.bucket(<BUCKET_URL>)
```

Here's a link to the constructor:
https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.bucket